# Correct way to make data access layer in modular architecture?

Tags: c#, architecture, data-access-layer

I am writing modular application in C#. I have "core", that separated into layers, like: DAL, BLL, and Presentation layer. So main question is about my DAL.

In my application I want to have oportunity to switch database. Because of that in my DAL I have 2 folders: Mysql and Postgresql.

I have tables: Persons, Bands, Songs and etc (15 tables).

To have all this tables in one place I created class DBData.

```
public interface IDBData
{
   IPersonsDAO Persons {get;}
   IBandsDAO   Bands {get;}
   ...
}

public interface IBandsDAO
{
 ICollection<Band> GetBandsByPersonsInBand(int personsCount);
 ICollection<Band> GetAll();
}
```

So, for examle in DAL/Postgresql I have

```
public class PostgresqlDbData : IDBData
{

 IConnectionFactory _connectionFactory

 //tables
 PostresqlPersonsDao _persons;
 PostresqlBandsDao _bands;


 PostgresqlDbData (IConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
 {
   _connectionFactory = _connectionFactory;
 }

  IPersonsDAO Persons get { return _persons ?? (_persons = new PostresqlPersonsDao (_connectionFactory)); }
  IBandsDAO   Bands get { return _bands?? (_bands = new PostresqlBandsDao (_connectionFactory)); }
  ...

}
```

This way I can easy get any dao table class in my code like:

```
IDBData dbData = new PostgresqlDbData (connectionFactory);

ICollection<Person> persons = dbData.Persons.GetSingers();
ICollection<Band> bands = dbData.Bands.GetBandsByPersonsInBand(7);
...
```

Why I did it like this?

Because I use dependency injection and I dont need anymore to type all tables I need in constructor of class, but I can just get all of them by getting instance only of IDBData.

```
///Some class that uses my IdbData

public class OrderService
{
 IDBData _dbData
 ShopService(IDBData dbData)
 {
  _dbData = dbData;
 }

 public void OrderAlbum(string albumName, string bandName)
 {
  ...
   IAlbum album = _dbData.Albums.GetAlbum(albumName, bandName);
  ..
 }

 public void OtherMethod(string personName)
 {
  ...
   _dbData.Persons.GetPerson(personName);
  ..
 }

}
```

As you can see in my OrderService I use _dbData. And it injected in constructor.

Yes, maybe it looks like Service Locator, but I can't find other way to make it better. If I did not do like this I would need to inject every table class in methods.

Like I said I have a modular application. So each module is independent but it knows about core. When module initializing it gets instance of IDBData.

For example I have module "BandsRaitingModule".

This is the main problem.

IBandsDAO has only 2 methods. But I need method like "GetBandsThatCreatedAt(int year)".
IBandsDAO dont have this method. In my module I want to do like

```
 // IBandsRaitingModuleData moduleDbData;

 ICollection<Band> bands = moduleDbData.Bands.GetBandsByPersonsInBand(7);
 ICollection<Band> bands = moduleDbData.Bands.GetBandsThatCreatedAt(7);
```

So I want to have ability to use my BandsRaitingModuleData as IDBData and same time use other methods.

Which is the best way to reach it?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Maybe you could re-read what you are asking and phrase it a little better?

Comment: Ok , short answer - How to organize my Data Access Layer to make it common for all modules, but in the same time each  module can have opportunity to add specific funcionality (i mean methods for DAL).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do some casting to a narrower interface to get the finer-grained functions.  So create an IBandsDAO interface with the narrower methods, and have it extend your IDBData interface.  This will require a downcast to that narrower interface, but will not force you into a particular provider interface, and thus still retain your encapsulation.